# iphone sdk: how to distinguish between touch and drag

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, drag, popover

i am using 2 pods.

`MMDrawerController 0.5.1`& `WYPopoverController 0.1.7`

now i want to make a WYPopover on my MMView

some pics:

this is how the `MMController` looks like (Playground)

[image: some playground]

now i want to touch it anywhere and make it look like:

[image: normal when touched]

**the error**: if i want to open the left view from the 'MMController' sometimes i get this:

[image: the error]

but it should look like (left MMControllerView)

[image]

i am using the 2 methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
// show the popoverController
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [popController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
}
```

my question: why the `touchesMoved` isn't called continuous and if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about the "pods" you mention (CocoaPods?) However, the most straightforward way to distinguish between taps and drags is to use a pair of gesture recognizers, a tap gesture recognizer and a pan gesture recognizer, and set up the tap gesture recognizer so the pan gesture must fail before the tap is triggered (There is a "wait until another gesture recognizer fails" mechanism built into gesture recognizers.)

I suggest reading up on UIGestureRecognizer, and the specific classes UITapGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss popover when your left menu is going to open,
i.e. you can do that in delegate method of your slide menu:
- menuWillOpen:  or something like this.

Comment: are you sure that delegate method was called?